# Issues when installing ASReml R/ Cannot remove prior version of ISLR

Tags: r

Warning:cannot remove prior version of 'ISLR'

> library(ISLR)
>   Error in library (ISLR)  :There is no package call ISLR

Lib paths is pointing to old installation path

Installed are 3.0 and 3.0.2 I am currently using 3.0.2

Do i need to uninstall 3.0 and will this solve the issue of the files being unzipped to the correct folder.

Thank you in advance